# if condition with less than on .length is not working precisely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a script in which the `#hsz-wrap2` is appended to the last visible div, and it should disappear when the number of divs are below or equal to **16** inside the `#snapshot_vertical` div.

However, the `if` condition is working in a way that I don't understand.

The div in the snippet should not appear, when adding the 16th div!

Why does this happen? What am I missing?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#snapshot_vertical > div').hide();
  $('#snapshot_vertical > div:lt(16)').show();


  $("#snapshot_vertical").append('<div style="font-size: 16px;text-align: center" id="hsz-wrap2"><span style="display: block;" id="megtobb-hsz2">Mégtöbb termék</span><br/><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/><span>Összesen még ' + ($("#snapshot_vertical > div").filter(":hidden").size()) + ' termék </span></div>');

  if ($('#snapshot_vertical > div').length <= 16) {

    $('#snapshot_vertical > div').show();
    $('#hsz-wrap2').hide();

  }
  $('#hsz-wrap2').click(function() {
    $('#snapshot_vertical > div').show();
    $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="snapshot-list-container">
  <div class="snapshot_vertical list grid-style list_with_divs" id="snapshot_vertical">
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">1.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">2.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">3.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">4.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">5.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">6.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">7.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">8.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">9.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">10.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">11.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">12.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">13.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">14.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">15.</div>
    <!--<div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">16.</div>--><!-- if you put this in the hsz-wrap2 appears, which is not normal (?) -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using `less that or equal to`condition . so when it equal to 16 `if `condition will become true

Comment: @Anant I've updated my question.

Comment: you appended id="hsz-wrap2" before calculate the divs length .. your 16 divs + appended div = 17 not 16 .. you can get the divs length before append div like so https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/azcsx1ks/1/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thank you so much! This is the solution! Answer it officially and I'll chose it as best!

Comment: @iorgu have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appended `id="hsz-wrap2"` div before you calculate the divs length ..So your 16 divs + appended div = 17 not 16 .. 
you can get the divs length before append div like this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#snapshot_vertical > div').hide();
  $('#snapshot_vertical > div:lt(16)').show();
  var length = $('#snapshot_vertical > div').length;

  $("#snapshot_vertical").append('<div style="font-size: 16px;text-align: center" id="hsz-wrap2"><span style="display: block;" id="megtobb-hsz2">Mégtöbb termék</span><br/><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/><span>Összesen még ' + ($("#snapshot_vertical > div").filter(":hidden").size()) + ' termék </span></div>');
 //alert($('#snapshot_vertical > div').length);
  if (length <= 16) {

    $('#snapshot_vertical > div').show();
    $('#hsz-wrap2').hide();

  }
  $('#hsz-wrap2').click(function() {
    $('#snapshot_vertical > div').show();
    $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="snapshot-list-container">
  <div class="snapshot_vertical list grid-style list_with_divs" id="snapshot_vertical">
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">1.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">2.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">3.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">4.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">5.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">6.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">7.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">8.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">9.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">10.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">11.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">12.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">13.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">14.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">15.</div>
    <div class="product-snapshot list_div_item">16.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```